# Lots of "missing character" messages in log file

Tags: tikz-pgf

Changing the default tip for arrows produces a lot of "missing character" messages in the log file. Is this a bug or is something wrong with the MWE?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Triangle]
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Log file :

```
[... snip ...]
Missing character: There is no p in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no t in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no p in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no t in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no p in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no t in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no p in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no t in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no p in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no t in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no p in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no t in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no p in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no t in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no p in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no t in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no p in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no t in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no p in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no t in font nullfont!
[... snip ...]
```

**Edit:** File list:

```
 *File List*
standalone.cls    2012/09/15 v1.1b Class to compile TeX sub-files standalone
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
 xkeyval.sty    2012/10/14 v2.6b package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2012/10/14 v2.6b key=value parser (HA)
standalone.cfg    2012/09/15 v1.1b Default configuration file for 'standalone' 
class
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
    tikz.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.142)
     pgf.sty    2013/12/18 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.14)
  pgfrcs.sty    2013/12/20 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.28)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
  pgfsys.sty    2013/11/30 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.47)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.25)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
 pgfmath.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
supp-pdf.mkii
 ***********
```

Comment: I think this is a duplicate, e.g.  [1](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41567/why-does-latex-report-errors-when-using-styles-in-a-tikz-pgf-picture), [2](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121154/tikzpicture-options-causing-there-is-no-in-font-nullfont), [3](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147722/tikzpicture-there-is-no-in-font-nullfont-but-no-extraneous-text), [4](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82741/tikz-gives-null-character-in-document).

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a duplicate because the other questions are concerned with line breaking in styles or other characters entered in the tikzpicture environment ...

Comment: Looks as if the library has somewhere a "pt" which shouldn't be there.

Comment: @PaulGaborit: You must look in the log-file.

Comment: In the definition of `\pgfmathdivide@` there is `\pgfmath@x =#1pt` and `#1`, in this case, is `\pgfarrowlength`; so the `pt` gets typeset; it wouldn't if `#1` were a number. This appears also for `#2`. Similarly in `\pgfmathsqrt@`, `\pgfmathcos@`, `\pgfmathsin@`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ok.

Comment: The manual (see "Customizing the Mathematical Engine")  does state that 'private' math macros ending in `@` such as `\pgfmathdivide@` and `\pgfmathadd@` expect numbers without units. So, the problem is with the code calling the private functions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TikZ sets the font to `\nullfont` inside environment `tikzpicture` to remove garbage, from the description of `tikzpicture` in the [PGF manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf):

> Next, the contents of the environment is processed and the graphic commands therein are put into a
>   box. Non-graphic text is suppressed as well as possible, but non-pgf commands inside a `{tikzpicture}` environment should not produce any "output" since this may totally scramble the positioning system
>   of the backend drivers. The suppressing of normal text, by the way, is done by temporarily switching
>   the font to `\nullfont`. You can, however, "escape back" to normal TEX typesetting. This happens, for
>   example, when you specify a node.

Commands in TikZ/PGf are often flexible, they accept either numbers (float or integer) or units as arguments. For example, the division is implemented in file `pgfmathfunctions.code.tex`:

```
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{divide}{2}{%
  \begingroup
    \pgfmath@x=#1pt\relax
    \pgfmath@y=#2pt\relax
    ...
}
```

This defines macro `\pgfmathdivide@`. The arguments `#1` and `#2` are stored in dimension registers `\pgfmath@x` and `\pgfmath@y`. The "default" unit `pt` is appended for the case `#1` and `#2` are numbers without unit. But if they contain a unit, then the appended letters `pt` are garbage. They are only thrown away by the current font `\nullfont` and you can see the lost char messages in the `.log` file.

### Debugging hints

The lost char messages can also be made visible on the console:

```
\tracinglostchars=2
```

The place, where `p` and `t` are set can be made visible by `\tracingcommands=1`. The following lines can be seen in the `.log` file:

```
{the letter p}
{the letter t}
```

(It is also written to the console with `\tracingonline=1`.)

Now the macros are of interest, that cause the setting of the letters:

```
\tracingmacros=1
```

Then the `.log` file contains:

```
\pgfmathdivide@ #1#2->\begingroup \pgfmath@x =#1pt\relax \pgfmath@y =#2pt\relax
 \let \pgfmath@sign =\pgfmath@empty \ifdim 0pt=\pgfmath@y \pgfmath@error {You'v
e asked me to divide `#1' by `#2', but I cannot divide any number by `#2'}\fi \
afterassignment \pgfmath@xa \c@pgfmath@counta \the \pgfmath@y \relax \ifdim 0pt
=\pgfmath@xa \divide \pgfmath@x by\c@pgfmath@counta \else \ifdim 0pt>\pgfmath@x
 \def \pgfmath@sign {-}\pgfmath@x =-\pgfmath@x \fi \ifdim 0pt>\pgfmath@y \expan
dafter \def \expandafter \pgfmath@sign \expandafter {\pgfmath@sign -}\pgfmath@y
 =-\pgfmath@y \fi \ifdim 1pt>\pgfmath@y \pgfmathreciprocal@ {\pgfmath@tonumber 
{\pgfmath@y }}\pgfmath@x =\pgfmath@sign \pgfmathresult \pgfmath@x \else \def \p
gfmathresult {0}\pgfmath@divide@periodtrue \c@pgfmath@counta =0\relax \pgfmathd
ivide@@ \pgfmath@x =\pgfmath@sign \pgfmathresult pt\relax \fi \fi \pgfmath@retu
rnone \pgfmath@x \endgroup 
#1<-\pgfarrowlength 
#2<-\pgfarrowwidth 
{\begingroup}
{\dimen107}
{the letter p}

Missing character: There is no p in font nullfont!
{the letter t}
Missing character: There is no t in font nullfont!
{\relax}
{\dimen108}
{the letter p}
Missing character: There is no p in font nullfont!
{the letter t}
Missing character: There is no t in font nullfont!
{\relax}
```

Thus one "culprit" is found: `\pgfmathdivide@`. A continued search also reveals
`\pgfmathsqrt@`, `\pgfmathcos@`, and `\pgfmathtan@`. That are the commands that outputs garbage `pt` in this example, but they are many other candidates, which also produces `pt`.

### Workaround

A cleanup macro can be inserted right after the assignment via `\afterassignment`. Package `etoolbox` provides `\patchcmd` for
an easier patching of the affected macros:

```
\tracinglostchars=2
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\def\cleanup@unit#1\@nil{}
\patchcmd{\pgfmathdivide@}{%
  \pgfmath@x=#1pt\relax
  \pgfmath@y=#2pt\relax
}{%
  \afterassignment\cleanup@unit
  \pgfmath@x=#1pt\relax\@nil
  \afterassignment\cleanup@unit
  \pgfmath@y=#2pt\relax\@nil
}{}{%
  \errmessage{Patching \string\pgfmathdivide@\space failed}%
}
\patchcmd{\pgfmathsqrt@}{%
  \expandafter\pgfmath@x#1pt\relax
}{%
  \afterassignment\cleanup@unit
  \expandafter\pgfmath@x#1pt\relax\@nil
}{}{%
  \errmessage{Patching \string\pgfmathsqrt@\space failed}%
}
\patchcmd{\pgfmathcos@}{%
  \expandafter\pgfmath@x#1pt\relax
}{%
  \afterassignment\cleanup@unit
  \expandafter\pgfmath@x#1pt\relax\@nil
}{}{%
  \errmessage{Patching \string\pgfmathcos@\space failed}%
}
\patchcmd{\pgfmathsin@}{%
  \expandafter\pgfmath@x#1pt\relax
}{%
  \afterassignment\cleanup@unit
  \expandafter\pgfmath@x#1pt\relax\@nil
}{}{%
  \errmessage{Patching \string\pgfmathsin@\space failed}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Triangle]
    % \tracingmacros=1
    % \tracingcommands=1
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Another way to fix this bug: replace all calls like `\pgfmathdivide@\pgfarrowlength\pgfarrowwidth` by `\pgfmathdivide@{\pgfmath@tonumber{\pgfarrowlength}}{\pgfmath@tonumber{\pgfarrowwidth}}` (in `pgflibraryarrows.meta.code.tex`).