# "There is no p in font nullfont" when drawing arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have studied that problem on Internet and I still cannot the solution to the following warning.  In **.log file** I get 20 times

```
Missing character: There is no p in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no t in font nullfont!
```

and I obviously don't use "pt" anywhere.  Is it possible that there is a problem in arrows.meta?  MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width=7,-{Triangle[angle=60:1 1.5]},postaction={draw,white,line width=6,shorten <=0.5,shorten >=0.9}] (6.36,9.5) -- (5.1,9.5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your example runs on my TL13 without problems.

Comment: @Johannes_B Have you checked .log file?

Comment: Oh, right. But those aren't error messages.

Comment: @Johannes_B Sorry.  What would be the right way to call them?

Comment: Information/warning Please have a look at [tikzpicture "There is no ... in font nullfont", but no extraneous text](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/147736)

Comment: This is the result of unnecessary `pt` in the PGF code. Something like `\somedimen=#1pt` where `#1` was expected to be a number without units but had units so the `pt` is output into the document. However inside a `tikzpicture` the font is set to `\nullfont` resulting in these warnings.

Comment: @MarkWibrow So it is essentially the problem in code?  Maybe it should be reported to the author?

Comment: @Pygmalion This has been reported multiple times. See also [tikzpicture options causing "There is no \[ in font nullfont!"?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/270627) The code behind pgf is HUGE and it is just a warning.

Comment: @Johannes_B I've seen that post.  In that case it was the error of the PGF user, and nobody mentioned that error was reported.  I know it is *just* a warning, but it slows down compiling (and I have to compile the whole document, because I have zillion of cross-references).

Comment: @AndrewSwann Well, I have the latest update (I have just re-checked that, just in case).  I guess this doesn't have anything to do with my platform (miktex), so perhaps reporting to PGF author would be still a good idea?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179297/lots-of-missing-character-messages-in-log-file/179313#179313 for a way to identify the command which throws out the garbage. (And I get the missing messages in a current TL14).

Comment: I can now confirm the messages.  I think this should be reported.

Comment: AFAICT in this case the problem is with the `arrows.meta` library as without the arrow specification there are no messages.

Comment: Here is a minimal example `\draw[-{Stealth[]}] (0,0) -- (0,1);` - the `Triangle[]` is just a customized to `Stealth`.  Replacing with `Circle` removes the warnings.

Comment: Some tickets for this bug ([1](http://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/334/), [2](http://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/314/)) already exist.

Comment: Thanks all for help.  So false alarm after all, as the warning has already been reported.  We simply have to wait...

Comment: I was disturbed writing a comment, so a little later: Does it really slow down? Can't notice that with the minimal example ;-) You can save *a lot* of time by externalizing the tikzpictures. if they don't change every time, you will get one slow compile and all following compiles are much faster.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a but which has been reported (links included in comments). But the question ought not be deleted as it is likely others encounter the same bug. (It may also be a duplicate here - I'm not entirely clear about that.)

Comment: @Johannes_B can you give me a hint how to externalize and pre-compile figures?  Possibly without having 100 external files with figures...

Comment: Have a look at the manual of tikz/pgf, there is a section for this. But the thing with externalization is, there will be external files. At least two for each tikzpicture.